# second call to browser.getAllWindowHandles causing error

Tags: protractor, socketexception

I have the following scenario in my protractor script: (certain pieces redacted due to confidentialilty)

```
  it('user story, screen captures', function() {

// Make sure page loads before screenshot happens
browser.waitForAngular();

// Mouseover the status element to get mouse away from toastr popup so the logout link will appear
browser.actions().mouseMove(createPage.menuDocview).perform();

// Sleep the browser to get rid of toastr popup
browser.sleep(5000);

// Take screenshot of page
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (jpg) {
  writeScreenShot(jpg, 'XXX.jpg');
});

// Click on the  menu item
createPage.menuDocview.click();

// Fill in a last name
createPage.lastName_input.sendKeys('smith');

// Click the Submit button
createPage.submitButton.click();

// Make sure page loads before screenshot happens
browser.waitForAngular();

// Mouseover the selected dataRow element
browser.actions().mouseMove(createPage.dataRow.get(3)).perform();

// Take screenshot of page
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (jpg) {
  writeScreenShot(jpg, 'XXX.jpg');
});

// Find the element we want (XXX) and click it
createPage.dataRow.get(3).click();

// Make sure page loads before screenshot happens
browser.waitForAngular();

// Take screenshot of page
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (jpg) {
  writeScreenShot(jpg, 'XXX.jpg');
});

// Mouseover the selected dataRow element
browser.actions().mouseMove(createPage.statusDiv.get(0)).perform();

// Sleep the browser to give popup a chance to show
browser.sleep(2000);

// Take screenshot of page
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (jpg) {
  writeScreenShot(jpg, 'XXX.jpg');
});

// Mouseover the button element
browser.actions().mouseMove(createPage.printPrescriber).perform();

// Take screenshot of page
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (jpg) {
  writeScreenShot(jpg, 'XXX.jpg');
});

// Click the button to get the report
createPage.printPrescriber.click();

// Switch to report window and screenshot it
// Sleep the browser for a few seconds to give it time to openup new window/tab
browser.sleep(5000);
// We'll need to switch to new window, so first grab the window handles...
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) { 
  // then grab our new window's handle...
  var mainWindowHandle = handles[0]; // this is your main window
  var newWindowHandle = handles[1]; // this is your new window
  // then switch to it.
  browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {
    // this next line is necessary since the generated page isn't Angular, and, as such, Protractor will timeout waiting for it to validate as an Angular page
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    // Take screenshot of page
    browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (jpg) {
      writeScreenShot(jpg, 'XXX.jpg');
    });

//        browser.close(); //close the current browser

    browser.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle) //Switch to main window
      .then(function(){
        // Mouseover the Print History button element
        browser.actions().mouseMove(createPage.printHistory).perform();

        // Take screenshot of page
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (jpg) {
          writeScreenShot(jpg, 'XXX.jpg');
        });

        // Click the button to get the report
        createPage.printHistory.click();
        // Switch to report window and screenshot it
        // Sleep the browser for a few seconds to give it time to openup new window/tab
        browser.sleep(12000);
        // We'll need to switch to new window, so first grab the window handles...
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {//THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE WHERE IT DIES 
          // then grab our new window's handle...
          var newWindowHandle2 = handles[2]; // this is your new window
          // then switch to it.
          browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle2).then(function () {
            // this next line is necessary since the generated page isn't Angular, and, as such, Protractor will timeout waiting for it to validate as an Angular page
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            // Take screenshot of page
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (jpg) {
              writeScreenShot(jpg, 'XXX.jpg');
            });
            // Just send true back since there's nothing we really want to commit to checking on the pdf. If there's a problem, we'll have it before this point.
            expect(true);
          });
        });
      });
  });
});

});
```

I built this little by little, basically adding each piece, before each screenshot, making sure it worked before moving on to the next piece. The final piece, starting at the second call to `browser.getAllWindowHandles()` crashes the script and generates an error of:

`Failed: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed`

I increased timeout times ridiculously (as you can see). I commented out the `browser.close()` in case that was doing it. Still getting it.

When I watch the test run, it does everything fine and even clicks the last button, generating the last report. It just croaks when I ask it to get the window handles that second time. I even get the screenshot right before it.

I've Googled extensively and even looked up that error on SO and am still lost as to why it's doing this.

Thanks!

EDIT: So, I just tried it with only the second report getting clicked. Same error. Could it be that the second report is too long? Clearly something is up with the second report (generated PDF from dynamic data). What kind of things would cause this error in a generated PDF?

EDIT 2: I increased the `browser.wait` to 20 seconds and still get it. I don't think it's a timing issue.

EDIT 3 (7/5): So, it seems like it may actually have something to do with timing. The new report window takes a bit to come up. If I sleep 5 seconds, I get an error that it can't find the handle yet since it doesn't exist. I move up to 6 seconds, and I get the socketException. Would this be a candidate to switch to using `browser.wait()` instead? How would I implement it in this scenario?

Comment: 2 thoughts. First, you can find a long discussion from Jim Evans that Selenium does not guarantee anything about the order of the handles, and you really ought to do something like checking the titles to be sure which is the latest popup. Second, I'm wondering if you need to add a wait for the handle to be featured like browser.wait(windowCount(2),30000,'wait for 2nd window ( popup)').then(function(){},function(err){//you could try to click again here});

Comment: where var windowCount= function(count){
      return function(){
        return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
          return handles.length >= count;
        });
      };
    }; //none of this was originally my code, I think it was from @alecxe. Also, what I meant about not relying on handle order was to use things like browser.driver.switchTo().window('claimResultsWindow') instead. Also to wait for things with browser.wait and something like the below.

Comment: var claimPopupIsPresent= function() {
      //side effect -- switches to the claim popup, fine
        return function() {
          return browser.driver.switchTo().window('claimResultsWindow').then(
               function()
                   {
                    return true;
                   },
               function(err) {
                   return false;
                }
              );
            }
       }

Comment: two more thoughts. If you are using IE, there are protected mode settings to worry about making the same. You may also need browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) in addition to the ingoreSynchronization.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! It doesn't seem to be a handle issue actually. It doesn't even really make it to that point. I've dug in more and it seems I'm getting an inexplicable error in the script. Somehow the whole user story actually works, but an error shows up at one point saying that the relevant query isn't defined. So, I'm working on nailing that down to see if that clears this up.

Comment: thanks for the update. So it is as if createPage goes stale or something at some point? Good luck.

Comment: Not sure. It almost seems at this point that there's an error in the back end perl script of the site and somehow the browser can recover from it, but protractor picks up on it and dies.

Comment: ARGH! So, I step-by-stepped it and that same error is being thrown earlier as well and protractor doesn't choke. Which means, that's not what's killing protractor. I'm getting the impression that I'm going to have to solve this internally. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Added a new edit in original post

Answer (score 1):

Handling browser handles can very tricky sometimes, especially for Mozilla and IE11.

Here is a method written for retrieving all browser handle title as a string. You can easily tweak the code and make it work for you in any condition.

```
/**
   * this method helps to get all window titles
   * @param windowTitle
   */
  async getAllRedirectedBrowserWindowTitles() {
    const title: string[] = [];
    await browser.wait(
      async () => {
        return (await browser.getAllWindowHandles()).length >= 2;
      },
      5000,
      `Only one browser handle found. There is no other browser handle to iterate`
    );
    const _windowHandles: string[] = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
    const _parentHandle: string = _windowHandles[0];
    for (const guid of _windowHandles) {
      if (guid !== _parentHandle) {
        await browser.switchTo().window(guid);
        await browser.wait(
          async () => {
            return (await browser.getTitle()) ? true : false;
          },
          5000,
          `Child browser title not loaded`
        );
        title.push(await browser.getTitle());
        await browser.close();
      }
    }
    await browser.switchTo().window(_parentHandle);
    return title;
  }
```

Now, you just need to call this method from anywhere in your code:

```
await getAllRedirectedBrowserWindowTitles(); //this will return the list of window title
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!!!!

I found this gem of a snippet elsewhere on SO and it did the trick.

```
 browser.driver.wait(function () {
            return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {

                if (handles.length > 1) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }, 10000, 'Waited for window count to be greater than 1');
```

I inserted this right before the 5 second sleep and it worked like a charm.
Also, to note, when I didn't close the first report window the second report window was not sitting at position 3 of the handles array. It inserted itself into position 2, pushing the first report to position 3.